# Getting error while trying to get "_RowId" (to pick up rows before it)

Tags: vb.net, datatable, row

I'm using `DataTable.Rows.Find` to find a specific row into a Datatable so to know how many rows are there before of it (because I need to pick up only them):

```
Using DT_DBData As DataTable = _
     DB_Functions.mQueryDT("SELECT * FROM UpdTest ORDER BY Row_Num")
    With DT_DBData
        .PrimaryKey = {.Columns("Id")}
    End With
    Dim mRow As DataRow = DT_DBData.Rows.Find("6")
```

But when I try to get `_RowId` to know how many rows are there before,

```
MsgBox(mRow._rowid)
```

I get error:

> Error 4 'System.Data.DataRow._rowID' is not accessible in this context
>   because it is 'Friend'

How can I fix?

Is there another way to get the number of rows before the found one?

**EDIT:**

At the moment I'm solving by using the below code to pick up the rows before the one found:

```
Dim NewRows() As DataRow
For x As Short = 0 To DT_DBData.Rows.Count - 1
    If Not DT_DBData.Rows(x).Equals(mRow) Then
        ReDim Preserve NewRows(x)
        NewRows(x) = DT_DBData.Rows(x)
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

I'll be grateful for better solutions

Comment: Can you explain why you need to know this information? Perhaps there is a better way

Comment: @Steve I need to know how many rows are there before the one found so to take only them from the DataTable

Comment: A DataTable.Select call with a proper condition could work as well I think

Comment: @Steve I'm not able to do this with a select. If you can (and it works) It will be an accepted answer

Comment: How about: `DT_DBData.Rows.Count`

Comment: @Hackerman This give me the total number of rows not the number of rows before the one found

Comment: @genespos this link might help you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/71ed2a79-5115-45f9-9ba4-fee80cfe9908/how-to-access-datarowrowid?forum=winformsdatacontrols

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your rdbms, but if you want reference the `Row_Num` you have to add it to your select.

```
DB_Functions.mQueryDT("SELECT *, Row_Num as row_id FROM UpdTest ORDER BY Row_Num")
```

Comment: I'm sorry to have created confusion. The showed code is only an example. In the real scenario I get data from a report (html table) and I put them into a DataTable so I have no control on how they are ordered. I edited the question showing how I'm solving (but I think there are better solutions)